# How to play 5.1 sound file from argument in C# console app?

Tags: c#, .net, audio

How can I play a 5.1 `.wav` or `.mp3` in C# console based app from an argument?

So something like this: `soundplayer.exe C:\sound\5.1.mp3` than it plays the file and closes the console window.

I have this:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Media;

namespace AudioPlayer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav");
            simpleSound.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure how to get the file from from a argument.
And it wont play the file embedded in the code.

The program opens and closes and vs debug shows `The thread 0x243c has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Comment: Did you do any research into reading generic command line arguments in C#, which is your underlying question, rather than jumping straight into "playing a sound from an argument"?

Comment: I assume you have `Main(string[] args)`, well `args` is an array of arguments so `args[0]` is the first one passed to the program, in your case the file path.

Comment: @Equalsk yes I have updated the code with my full one.

Comment: @JamesThorpe No not yet I want to get to play something directly first to make sure it works which it dont.

Comment: Right, so `var simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(args[0]);` will play whatever is passed as the first argument, e.g. `cmd YourSoundPlayer.exe "C:\Path\To\Sound\test.wav"`. Seriously, there are countless tutorials on this...

Comment: @Equalsk ok, thanks but why does my current code not play the embedded file?

Comment: How should I know? You've just edited that into the question and provided no useful information about what actually happens. Does nothing happen? Do you receive an error? Have you tried debugging? A try/catch? Saying "it won't play" is not useful.

Comment: @Equalsk it opens and closes and VS debug  shows `The thread 0x243c has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Comment: The code is fine, it plays the chime for me. Are other sounds in Windows working? It would throw an error if it could not find that file. To me it sounds like it's playing the chime just fine and environmental factors are stopping you from hearing it like having system sounds volume turned down...

Comment: @Equalsk yes sound works fine, but my speakers are 5.1

Comment: @Equalsk hmm.. I have to turn the volume to max and only part of the file is played if anything.

Comment: Good, as soon as you provided the right information about it playing part of the sound I can answer the question :-)

Comment: @Equalsk adding  `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` seems to fix it.

Comment: Using `Thread.Sleep(1000)` causes the window to block for long enough for the sound to complete, a wav longer than 1 second would still get cut off. It's a hack at best, use playsync as advised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs because the [Play()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.play(v=vs.110).aspx) method of [SoundPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) does not block so the command window closes before the file is played.

Use the [PlaySync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync.aspx) method instead.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav");
    simpleSound.PlaySync();
}
```

To play the sound provided as the first argument:

```
var simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(args[0]);
simpleSound.PlaySync();
```

In CMD:

> YourSoundPlayer.exe "C:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav"

Comment: Thanks this works fine But why is a double qoute needed in the argument?

Comment: You mean in the command line argument? Technically in this case it isn't needed, it would be if the path contained spaces so I'm just in the habit of always including them.

Comment: The question asks for WAV or MP3 files. Sadly the primitive SoundPlayer class does not play mp3 files. Midi neither. Shame on Microsoft.